# How do I check for brackets in a specific place in the string?

Tags: javascript, string, brackets

I have this code and it needs to returns true or false based on the string you give it.
This is the only example on which it doesn't work. How can I check if brackets exist in a specific index of the string?

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {

var newStr = str.replace(/-/g,'').replace(/ /g,'').replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
var valid = true;
var re = /\([^()]*\)/g;
while (str.match(re))
    str = str.replace(re, '');
if (str.match(/[()]/)){
  valid = false;
}
if(newStr.length === 10 && valid === true && str.indexOf()){
  return true;
}else if(newStr.length === 11 && str[0] != "-" && newStr[0] == 1 && valid === true){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
}

telephoneCheck("(6505552368)");
```

Comment: Use an appropriate regex. What are the rules?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

Comment: You are using `str.indexOf()` without the search value parameter. It is required for the method to work.

Comment: Given `valid` can only be `true` or `false` there's no need to check `valid === true`, you can just write `valid` by itself. That said I'm not sure you need the `valid` variable at all when you could just `return false` immediately rather than storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
'(6505552368)'.replace(/^\((\d+)\)$/, '$1');
```

The `^` and `$` in the RegExp will match the start and the end of the string. The `\d+` will match one or more numbers. The extra parentheses form a capture group that is then used in the replacement as `$1`.

You might be better off doing more work using RegExps rather than doing all that replacing but without knowing the exact requirements it's difficult to be more precise. I highly suggest learning more about RegExp syntax.

If you literally just want to know whether **'brackets exist in a specific index'** then you can just use:

```
str.charAt(index) === '(';
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if there are brackets at a specific index in the string:

`/[()]/.test(str[index])`

To check if there are any brackets in the string at all:

`/[()]/.test(str)`

If you want to test for a specific bracket type (e.g. opening but not closing) remove the other one (e.g. closing) from the regex.

Comment: How are you trying to use it? Can you give me an example of what you're using it for.